# Chrome Dinosaur Game in C++ Applying OOPs

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, game

I am gaining a lot of interest in Game development.
I created Chrome Dinosaur game in C++.

I have not paid much attention to UI/UX, just trying to see if i can apply some OOPs in game programming.

As I'm a beginner, I'm not sure whether I'm using good code design and logic.

I could use some code review and tips. Before I get my hands dirty in Game Programming.

The code is also in GitHub https://github.com/ankushTripathi/DinoBIT.

## Config.h

here i define all my constants, to make code configurable from single file.

```
#pragma once
#define MAX_FRAME_RATE 400
#define CONSOLE_EXIT_KEY 'q'
#define CONSOLE_JUMP_KEY ' '
#define TREE_SYMBOL 'T'
#define DINO_SYMBOL 'x'
#define BLANK_SYMBOL '-'
#define INITAL_PADDING 2

#define PLAY_AREA_SIZE  22
#define MAX_TREE_DISTANCE  5
#define FRAME_RATE_REDUCTION 50
#define LEVEL_UP_FACTOR  3

#define PLAYER_START_POSITION 0
#define PLAYER_SPEED 1
#define PLAYER_JUMP_SPAN 3
```

## Console.h

Abstract class, I understood consoles are handled differently in different OS. Implement Console class for required OS.

```
#pragma once
#include "Config.h"

class Console
{
protected:

    int frame_rate;
    char input_value;
    static const char exit_key = CONSOLE_EXIT_KEY;
    static const char jump_key = CONSOLE_JUMP_KEY;
    std::string output;

public:

    virtual void ClearScreen() = 0;
    virtual void Display(const std::string& str = "") = 0;
    virtual void Sleep() = 0;

    virtual void WaitForInput() = 0;
    virtual bool KeyPressed() = 0;
    virtual bool IsExitKey() = 0;
    virtual bool IsJumpKey() = 0;

    virtual void SetOutput(std::string) = 0;
    virtual void DecrementFameRate() = 0;
};
```

## Win32Console.h

Extending Console class for Windows 32bit.

```
#pragma once
#ifdef _WIN32

#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>
#include <string>

#include "Console.h"

class Win32Console : public Console
{

public :

    Win32Console();

    void ClearScreen();
    void Display(const std::string& str);
    void Sleep();

    void SetOutput(std::string output);
    void DecrementFameRate();

    void WaitForInput();
    bool KeyPressed();
    bool IsExitKey();
    bool IsJumpKey();

    ~Win32Console();
};

#endif // _WIN32
```

## Win32Console.cpp

Implementation of above class

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "Config.h"
#include "Win32Console.h"

Win32Console::Win32Console()
{
    frame_rate = MAX_FRAME_RATE;
    input_value = '\0';
    output = "";
}

void Win32Console::ClearScreen()
{
    std::cout << "\033[2J\033[1;1H" << std::flush;
}

void Win32Console::Display(const std::string& str)
{
    if (!str.length())
        std::cout << output << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << str << "\n";
}

void Win32Console::Sleep()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(frame_rate));
}

void Win32Console::SetOutput(std::string output)
{
    this->output = output;
}

void Win32Console::DecrementFameRate()
{
    this->frame_rate -= FRAME_RATE_REDUCTION;
}

void Win32Console::WaitForInput()
{
    std::cin.get(input_value);
}

bool Win32Console::KeyPressed()
{
    bool result = _kbhit();
    if (result) input_value = _getch();
    return result;
}

bool Win32Console::IsExitKey()
{
    return (input_value == exit_key);
}

bool Win32Console::IsJumpKey()
{
    return (input_value == jump_key);
}


Win32Console::~Win32Console()
{
}

#endif // _WIN32
```

## Win64Console.h

Extending console class for Windows 64bit

```
#pragma once
#ifdef _WIN64

#include "Win32Console.h"

class Win64Console :
    public Win32Console
{
public :
    void ClearScreen() override;
};

#endif
```

## Win64Console.cpp

```
#ifdef _WIN64

#include "Win64Console.h"

void Win64Console::ClearScreen()
{
    std::cout << std::string(100, '\n');
}

#endif // _WIN64
```

## ConsoleFactory.h

Factory pattern to get Console of compatible OS and Architecture.

```
#pragma once
#include "Win32Console.h"
#include "Win64Console.h"

class ConsoleFactory
{
public:
    static Console* GetConsole();
};
```

## ConsoleFactory.cpp

```
#include "ConsoleFactory.h"

Console* ConsoleFactory::GetConsole()
{
#ifdef __unix
    return new Console();
#endif // __unix
#ifdef __APPLE__
    return new Console();
#endif // __APPLE__
#ifdef _WIN64 
    return new Win64Console();
#endif  //_WIN64
#ifdef _WIN32 
    return new Win32Console();
#endif // _WIN32 
}
```

## Player.h

Instance of this class represents Dino.

```
#pragma once
#include "Config.h"

class Player
{
protected:

    int position;
    int speed;
    int jump_span;
    int score;
    static int high_score;

public :

    Player();

    int GetPosition();
    int GetJumpSpan();

    void Run();
    void Jump();

    int GetScore();
    void SetScore(int);

    int GetHighScore();

    ~Player();
};
```

## Player.cpp

```
#include "Player.h"

int Player::high_score = 0;

Player::Player() :
    position(PLAYER_START_POSITION),
    speed(PLAYER_SPEED),
    jump_span(PLAYER_JUMP_SPAN),
    score(0)
{
}

int Player::GetPosition()
{
    return position;
}

int Player::GetJumpSpan()
{
    return jump_span;
}

void Player::Run()
{
    position += speed;
    SetScore(position);
}

void Player::Jump()
{
    position += jump_span;
}

int Player::GetScore()
{
    return score;
}

void Player::SetScore(int score)
{
    this->score = score;
    high_score = (high_score > score)? high_score : score;
}

int Player::GetHighScore()
{
    return high_score;
}

Player::~Player()
{
}
```

## Game.h

the main class for this game.

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include<random>

#include "Player.h"
#include "ConsoleFactory.h"
#include "Config.h"


class Game
{

private:

    static Console* console;
    static Player player;

    static bool jump_flag;
    static int last_frame;
    static int last_tree_position;
    static const int play_area_size = PLAY_AREA_SIZE;
    static std::deque<bool> play_area;

    static std::mt19937 eng;

    static bool GameOverConditions();

    static bool IsLevelUp();
    static void LevelUp();

    static bool ShouldPlaceTree(int);
    static void Move();
    static std::string GenerateFrame();

    static bool Run();

public:

    static void Start();
    static void Loop();
    static bool ShouldRestart();
    static void Restart();

    static void End();
};
```

## Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

Console* Game::console = ConsoleFactory::GetConsole();
Player Game::player = Player();

std::mt19937 Game::eng{ std::random_device{}() };

bool Game::jump_flag = false;
int Game::last_frame = Game::play_area_size - 1;
int Game::last_tree_position = 0;
std::deque<bool> Game::play_area(Game::play_area_size, false);

std::string Game::GenerateFrame()
{

    std::string str = "Current Score :" + std::to_string(player.GetScore()) + "\t High Score :" + std::to_string(player.GetHighScore()) + "\n";
    std::string result = "";
    for (auto it = play_area.begin(); it != play_area.end(); it++)
    {
        result += (*it) ? TREE_SYMBOL : BLANK_SYMBOL;
    }

    result[0] = DINO_SYMBOL;
    result = std::string(INITAL_PADDING, BLANK_SYMBOL) + result;
    return str + result;
}

void Game::Start()
{
    console->ClearScreen();
    console->Display("Welcome To DinBIT (press [space] to jump ..)");
    console->WaitForInput();

    for (int i = 1;i < play_area_size; i++)
    {
        if (ShouldPlaceTree(i))
        {
            play_area[i] = true;
            last_tree_position = i;
        }
    }

    console->SetOutput(GenerateFrame());
}

void Game::Loop()
{
    while (1)
    {

        console->ClearScreen();
        console->Display();
        console->Sleep();

        if (!Run())
        {
            if (ShouldRestart())
                Restart();
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}

bool Game::ShouldRestart()
{
    console->ClearScreen();
    console->Display();
    console->WaitForInput();

    console->ClearScreen();
    console->Display("Press [Enter] to restart, 'q' to quit..");

    console->WaitForInput();

    return !(console->IsExitKey());
}

void Game::Restart()
{
    Game::console = ConsoleFactory::GetConsole();
    Game::player = Player();

    Game::jump_flag = false;
    Game::last_frame = Game::play_area_size - 1;
    Game::last_tree_position = 0;
    Game::play_area = std::deque<bool>(Game::play_area_size, false);

    Game::Start();
}

void Game::End()
{
    console->ClearScreen();
    console->Display();

    console->WaitForInput();

    delete console;
}
```

## Logic.cpp

All Game Logic is implemented Here..

```
#include "Game.h"

bool Game::GameOverConditions()
{
    return (play_area[0] || play_area[1]);
}

bool Game::IsLevelUp()
{
    return !((last_frame + 1) % (LEVEL_UP_FACTOR * play_area_size));
}


void Game::LevelUp()
{
    console->DecrementFameRate();
}

bool Game::Run()
{
    jump_flag = false;

    if(console->KeyPressed() && console->IsJumpKey())
    {
        jump_flag = true;
        player.Jump();
    }


     if (IsLevelUp())
    {
         Game::LevelUp();
    }


    Move();

    std::string str = GenerateFrame();
    if (jump_flag) str += "\n JUMPED !";

    if (GameOverConditions())
    {
        str += "\nGame Over";
        console->SetOutput(str);
        return false;
    }

    console->SetOutput(str);
    return true;
}


bool Game::ShouldPlaceTree(int frame)
{
    if (frame - last_tree_position >= MAX_TREE_DISTANCE)
        return std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type>{0,1}(eng);

    return false;
}

void Game::Move()
{
    if (!jump_flag)
        player.Run();

    play_area.pop_front();
    last_frame++;

    if (ShouldPlaceTree(last_frame))
    {
        play_area.push_back(true);
        last_tree_position = last_frame;
    }
    else
        play_area.push_back(false);

    if (jump_flag)
    {
        int j = player.GetJumpSpan();

        while (--j)
        {
            play_area.pop_front();
            last_frame++;

            if (ShouldPlaceTree(last_frame))
            {
                play_area.push_back(true);
                last_tree_position = last_frame;
            }
            else
                play_area.push_back(false);
        }
    }
}
```

## main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

int main()
{
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    std::cout.tie(NULL);

    Game::Start();
    Game::Loop();
    Game::End();
}
```

There is a mini ReadMe https://github.com/ankushTripathi/DinoBIT/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I assume you're referring to [this game](https://www.radiotimes.com/news/2015-05-28/google-chromes-secret-unable-to-connect-to-the-internet-game-could-be-better-than-the-whole-web/)?

Comment: Yes that one..I don't know it's name.. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Defines as defines

I do not understand why you copy these precompiler macros to class constants:

```
static const char exit_key = CONSOLE_EXIT_KEY;
static const char jump_key = CONSOLE_JUMP_KEY;
```

Can't you use the macros directly?

### Const methods

Any method that does not modify any member variable in `this` should be made `const`; the most obvious example is this:

```
virtual void Display(const std::string &str = "") const = 0;
```

### Const arguments

It's better to pass const references when possible, i.e.

```
virtual void SetOutput(const std::string &output) = 0;
```

### Typo

`DecrementFameRate` is most likely supposed to be `DecrementFrameRate`.

### Parens

`return` does not need parens in either of these cases:

```
return (input_value == exit_key);

return (input_value == jump_key);
```

### Combining preprocessor predicates

```
#ifdef __unix
    return new Console();
#endif // __unix
#ifdef __APPLE__
    return new Console();
#endif // __APPLE__
```

can be

```
#if defined(__unix) || defined(__APPLE__)
    return new Console();
#endif
```

see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html for more details.

### High scores

I question the placement of this variable:

```
static int high_score;
```

If it truly is a high score per player, then it should not be made `static`. If this is not per-player, perhaps it deserves to live in `Game` instead.

### Object ownership

Your `Game::console` is passed in from the `ConsoleFactory`, where you are then responsible for deleting it. The safer way to track this, rather than a bare pointer, is a `shared_ptr` (what used to be an `auto_ptr`). Among other things, this will simplify your destructor.

### Re-entrance

As it is currently implemented, `Game` does not deserve to be a class; at most just a collection of methods and variables in a namespace. What if - down the road - you need to refactor this so that you're running a game server that can host multiple games? You should remove `static` from this, and if there is the current need for this to be a singleton, there are better ways to represent singletons. There are [many, many different methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern).

### For loops

I find this:

```
    int j = player.GetJumpSpan();

    while (--j)
```

easier to read as

```
for (int j = player.GetJumpSpan(); j > 0; j--)
```

Comment: "As it is currently implemented, Game does not deserve to be a class; at most just a collection of methods and variables in a namespace" , thats exactly how i felt but wasnt sure how to handle it..